# Wordpress - Front-end registration plus user profile data

Tags: wordpress

So I managed to create a front-end registration page for my wordpress site.
But I still want to add some user data such as Twitter, Facebook, Google Plus and Bio as required data on registration.
I searched for solution but I ended up with plugins, and I don't like the idea of using plugin for that.

Here is the current code that I got from a tutorial:

http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html

I just want to know what should I add, or is this possible.

Thanks.

Comment: "I don't like the idea of using plugin for that" - that's pretty much all a plugin is, though: some PHP to add a page and the database backend. They're pretty straightforward so if you're able to write PHP you should be able to audit them to make sure you're happy with them. I would look at a plug-in as a starting point at least.

Comment: But i do not like these plugins to bug me with their "updates".

Comment: I don't know the exact mechanism that uses, but if you edit or remove the `/* Plugin Name */` block, or rename the plugin to your own name, then it ought to stop it. Packaging your own solution as a plug-in is likely the right thing to do though, whether you start from scratch or borrow someone else's plug-in as starting point, to allow you to upgrade the core WordPress independently of your changes anyway.